# How to update view after done with the progress bar?

Tags: android, android-listview, progress-bar

**CASE:** I have a button and list-view in the activity. On click of the button I have added a click listener, which starts a new thread in which I update the progress bar. After the job is done i.e. progress bar is done 100%, I want to update the list-view.

```
final OnClickListener mStartScan = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // prepare for a progress bar dialog
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
        progressBar.setCancelable(false);
        progressBar.setMessage(getString(R.string.text_scanning_inbox));
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(totalSms);
        progressBar.show();

        progressBarStatus = 0;

        Thread progressThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressBarStatus < totalSms) {

                    // process some tasks
                    progressBarStatus = someStuff();

                    // Update the progress bar
                    progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (progressBarStatus >= done) {

                    // sleep 1 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // close the progress bar dialog
                    progressBar.dismiss();

                    // this method updates the list
                    populateList();
                }
            }
        });
        progressThread.start();

//          try {
//              progressThread.join();
//          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          } finally {
//              populateList();
//          }           
        }
};
```

**PROBLEM:** When I update the listview after completion of the task and dismissing progress bar, I get an exception which says that the view can be updated only from the thread in which it is created.

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

**WHAT ELSE I TRIED:** I tried waiting for the thread which is running progress bar to complete and then update listview from the main thread.

```
try {
    progressThread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    populateList();
}
```

However, this does not work. It does not show the progress bar at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because of the fact that you are trying to change the UI components on a secondary thread. You should read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more information on how to use threads on Android.

You can use the `Activity` method `runOnUIThread()` to call the `populateList()` method or whatever makes the updates on the UI(main) thread. If you read the doc mentioned above, you will find out more about this.

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```
private ProgressDialog progressBar;

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        progressBar.setMessage("please, waiting ...");
        progressBar.setCancelable(false);
        progressBar.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            // get info and set them in my model ...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return params[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (null != progressBar && progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }

        // do work in UI and set info adapter and refresh list ...
        populateList();
                    myListView.invalidateViews();
    }
}
```

for more information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Here original thread refers to the ui thread. You are attempting to update ui inside a thread which is not possible.

You cannot update ui from the back ground thread. You can use runOnUiThread .

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui threa
  {
      public void run() 
      { 

      }
   });
```

I would suggest you to use asynctask

You use use asynctask for this purpose. The onPreExecute(), onPostExecute()  are invoked on the ui thread and you can use the same to update ui. You can do your background computation in doInbackground()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Check the topic under heading The 4 steps.

```
    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // background computation and publish progress      
    return null;
}
    @Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
           // update progress bar
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
            // cancel the progress bar
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
             //display progress bar    
}

}
```

Load asynctask on the ui thread

```
     new TheTask().execute().
```